# root disk formatted with ZFS

Tags: boot, system-installation, zfs

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 or 21.10 with ZFS on root disk.
I can't find an option to use ZFS (just xfs and btrfs) in the installer.

Is there a way to boot from a ZFS formatted disk?

Answer (score 1):

Since [Eoan Ermine (Ubuntu 19.10)](https://ubuntu.com/blog/enhancing-our-zfs-support-on-ubuntu-19-10-an-introduction), Ubuntu installer for desktop only can use ZFS as root file-system but is **still experimental**.

The current LTS, [Focal Fossa (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://ubuntu.com/blog/zfs-focus-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-whats-new) provides only a mono-disk installation, I do not know the difference with a server installer, but this is the only *Ubuntu way* to install on a root ZFS.

However, OpenZfs provide a way to install Ubuntu on ZFS root:

https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/index.html#root-on-zfs